# Dependency Walker shows up @x after function names

Tags: c++, c, dll, dllexport

I'm writing a plugin DLL for a piece of software and the DLL compiles fine, but the software is not able to access the DLL's functions. I do know that the software is aware of the DLL though.

When I examine the DLL in Dependency Walker, the function names have `@x` appended to the end, e.g. `Foo@4` which means that Foo has 1 parameter (number of function parameters multiplied by 4).

However, when I examine a plugin DLL which is known to work the DLL functions do not have `@x` appended at the end. Since this DLL is known to work and my DLL does not work, I think this has something to do with it.

The DLL that works uses `__declspec(dllexport) __stdcall` on its exported functions. Note that I only have the source code of the good DLL. I know it works because I have the DLL file itself, which I haven't compiled myself. As far as I know this was compiled in the Borland IDE, so it's probably an Eclipse specific problem here?

Does anyone know what might be wrong and/or how I can make the DLL work properly?

**EDIT** I should point out I'm using Eclipse IDE, with MINGW compiler.

Comment: How do you export? You should use `.def` file to generate undecorated names

Comment: Presumably Eclipse is doing the export automatically. Currently I'm using `__stdcall(dllexport)`

Comment: I assume, you mean `__declspec(dllexport)` and use microsoft compilers. This way you have to create [.def](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) file and define exported functions' names in it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean that.

Comment: Oh, and I don't know about Eclipse, but ms linker uses it with `-def:filename`

Comment: Just to be sure: don't other plugins' functions have underscore prefixed? 'cause if they do you have to follow MSalters' advice

Answer (score 4):

The names that Dependency Walker shows are the true names. They are decorated names and the presence of `@<num>` indicates a `__stdcall` function exported with `__declspec(dllexport)`.

If you linked to the DLL at load-time using the import library (.lib file) supplied with it, then the mapping between the true name and the decorated name would be contained in that import library. If you link at run-time with `GetProcAddress` then you need to use the decorated name.

Since you are writing a plugin then the host will be using run-time linking. And you will have to comply with its specific naming conventions. That means you need to suppress name decoration. For a `__stdcall` function that means that you must export the functions using a .def file rather than `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Of course, it is plausible that you got the calling convention wrong when you wrote your plugin. Perhaps the host expects `cdecl`. I cannot tell from here which calling convention you should be using. The documentation of the host app will presumably specify the calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

The `@x` syntax means that the caller must clean up `x` bytes of stack. That's because you used the `_stdcall` calling convention. The existing code assumes `_cdecl` functions, won't clean up the stack, and won't work with your DLL for that reason.

Comment: You cannot know that the host assumes `__cdecl`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The known-good plugin DLL seems to use `__cdecl`, and that works. Since the calling conventions break pretty hard if there's a mismatch, it's safe to assume the caller also uses `__cdecl`

Comment: Take a look at Win32 API functions. They are `__stdcall` and not decorated. You simply cannot know what calling convention the host assumes. This article seems relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/27/679634.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know. I consider that a special case, though: that API is supposed to be language-neutral. IIRC< it started as `_pascal` calling convention

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that export undecorated names. It is not uncommon for a library to be language neutral. For a plugin architecture that would be a common goal. Of course, the functions may indeed be `__cdecl`. My point is that you cannot state that with any certainty.